# Cannot install python packages from source-code

Tags: python, linux

I need to install `PIL` (python imaging library) on my Ubunto10.4-32bit (EDIT:64bit) machine on my python2.5.4-32bit. 
This question is also relevant to any other source package I guess (among those that I need are `RPyC`,`psyco` and `numpy`).

I downloaded the source-code since I can't find any neat package to do the job and did
a 
`sudo python2.5 setup.py install`.
output:

```
Could not find platform dependent libraries <exec_prefix>
Consider setting $PYTHONHOME to <prefix>[:<exec_prefix>]
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "setup.py", line 9, in <module>
    import glob, os, re, struct, string, sys
  File "/usr/lib/python2.5/struct.py", line 30, in <module>
    from _struct import Struct, error
ImportError: No module named _struct
```

but

> > echo $PYTHONHOME
> >     
> > /usr

Well, in the file `struct.py` theres the line `from _struct import Struct, error`
This is part of the python source code itself so I really wonder whats wrong with the python installation, since the code fails to import the module.
I installed py2.5.4 by doing:

```
./configure --prefix=/usr
make altinstall
```

(using `make altinstall` since I need py26 as default python interpreter)

EDIT: This issue might have risen from mistakenly using a 64bit platform :) and 32bit python2.5 . So anyhow problem solved by reducing unnecessary complexities - switching to 32bit machine and porting app to python 2.6.

Comment: The debian package is called `python-imaging`. I would assume Ubuntu has an analog.

Comment: Try to use `easy_install python-imaging`

Comment: @Anatolij: That's not such a great idea. Ubuntu's own package manager is [more likely](http://workaround.org/easy-install-debian) to yield good (maintainable) results than easy_install.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

#### In short:

Try using the Ubuntu repository first. If the package isn't there, use `easy_install`. If all fails, download the package directly to your source folder.

#### Ubuntu repository (the apt-get approach)

Ubuntu (10.04 and newer) has most mainstream packages are available with `apt-get`. The naming convention is `python-NAME`, e.g. `python-imaging` or `python-scipy`.

This is the best way to go, since the native package manager will handle any dependencies and updates issues.

Run `apt-cache search python | grep "^python-" | less` to see a list of packages available for your system (I have over 1,200 in my 10.04 machine).

#### Setuptools

For packages that are not part of the Ubuntu repository, you can use the python `easy-install` tool. First, install the setup tool:

```
sudo apt-get install python-setuptools
```

And you can install any Python package, e.g. [colorworld](http://pypi.python.org/pypi/colorworld/0.3), using `easy-install`:

```
sudo easy_install colorworld
```

This gives you some degree of protection (e.g., handles dependencies) but updates are generally manual, and it's a real pain to reinstall all these packages in a new computer.

#### Manual download

You can always download the source code to some directory and add it to your `PYTHONPATH`. It's the best approach when you just need to evaluate a package or apply some quick-and-dirty solution.

Answer (score 2):

```
sudo aptitude install python-imaging
```

This will install PIL library.

Answer (score 0):

```
sudo aptitude install python-imaging
```

That will install PIL. But I'm not really sure how to help with your other packages. Maybe try searching for them in synaptic.